# Как получить вероятность принадлежности к заданному классу в xgboost.XGBClassifier?

Tags: python, xgboost

Есть 4 класса,

> 1; AA; 2; BB

образец столбца с классами прикладываю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Создание объекта XGB:

```
prm = {'num_class': 4, 'objective': 'multi:softmax'}                 
XGB = xgboost.XGBClassifier()
XGB.set_params(**prm)
```

обучение XGB:

```
XGB.fit(train_data, train_labels, train_weights)
```

При попытке использовать:

```
XGB.predict_proba(test_data)[:,3]
```

выдает ошибку

> IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4

в выходном массиве вероятностей присутствуют только 3 столбца вместо 4х

Как узнать вероятность для конкретного класса, например для класса

> AA

?

Comment: а как вы создавали объект `XGB` ?

Comment: @MaxU поправила вопрос

Comment: @АннаЛебедева А какие размеры у `train_labels`? И хорошо бы примеры данных привести - по нескольку строк из train_data, train_labels, test_data. Просто может у вас в train_labels только три класса и есть.

Comment: @CrazyElf и вправду оказалось 3 класса, вместо 4 на тренировке. Для общего развития, тем не менее интересно как получить вероятности именно для класса 'AA' или как узнать какой XGB присваивает ему номер

Comment: @АннаЛебедева Покажите ваш train_labels, скорее всего в каком порядке там классы, в таком XGB их и предсказывает

Comment: @CrazyElf приложила к вопросу скриншот с образцом данных

Comment: @АннаЛебедева Понятнее не стало. Покажите питоновские объекты train_data, train_labels, хотя бы кусок их какой-то.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При обучении в качестве `y` вы использовали матрицу размером `n x m`, где `n` - число сэмплов, `m` - число классов в таргете.

Соответственно, `predict_proba` у моделей тоже обычно выдаёт в таких случаях матрицу размером `n x m` с вероятностями для каждого класса по каждому сэмплу.

Таким образом, массив вероятностей для первого класса из списка можно получить так (нумерация классов начинается с 0, как и все нумерации в питоне):

```
XGB.predict_proba(test)[:,0]
```

То есть берём с помощью среза первый столбец у предсказанной матрицы вероятностей.

И ещё раз что касается порядка классов. Каким столбцом в `y` (или `labels`) у вас идут значения для класса `AA`, такой же столбец с вероятностями и надо смотреть в `predict_proba`.

Comment: поправила вопрос.